# Не могу установить Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2, npm, angular

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...emat-progress-reporte'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tigran\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-12T13_39_40_032Z-debug.log
```

Такая вот ошибка,переустанавливал node, не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте кроме удаления Node очистить папки npm и npm cache в AppData\Roaming\ и сделайте перезагрузку компа.